# How to create a static file cache in HHVM

Tags: hhvm

We are running a website in Repo Authoritative mode on HHVM.

I can compile the code files fine with the `hhvm --hphp -thhbc`. 
However, it seems like there is also a feature to create a static file cache with `-tfilecache`, which it will use to serve static files, and I can't get this to work. There is very little documentation around this feature and I couldn't find anything on Google.

I am generating a file list like this:

```
find . -type f -not \( -name '*.php' -or -name '*.phtml' \) >/tmp/staticfiles
```

and trying to generate the cache like this:

```
hhvm --hphp -t filecache -v AllVolatile=true --input-list /tmp/staticfiles -l3
```

(-l3 added for verbose logging)

and the result is always:

```
running hphp...
creating temporary directory /tmp/hphp_H98a3V ...
parsing inputs...
parsing inputs took 0'00" (145 us) wall time

Assertion failure: /tmp/tmp.jRkkBo6M6b/hphp/compiler/analysis/analysis_result.cpp:79: virtual HPHP::AnalysisResult::~AnalysisResult(): assertion `!m_finish' failed.


Core dumped: Aborted
Stack trace in /tmp/stacktrace.1767.log
hphp failed
running hphp took 0'01" (1257721 us) wall time
```

with nothing in that stacktrace file.

I've tried with just one or two files in the list, same result. Experienced on HHVM 1.14.2 and 1.14.4, on RHEL 7.2.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I'm also stuck with same problem on HHVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a [bug](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/7575) and they got back really fast with

> You probably want to create the repo and the filecache at the same time. You can pass --file-cache /where/to/create/cache to the command you use for building the hhbc repo.

which worked like a charm, I had no idea you could do the two together.

They did leave the bug open, so it looks like it's supposed to work standalone too. But this method is good enough for me (actually better)